# Socket programming python ,unexpected results with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to process results at server until the client press "6" .

1 .I send a choice from client to server about what to do .(suppose he presses 1 - asking to search for a word )

2 client is prompted to enter the word.

3 server searches and return true or false accordingly.

4 client is presented with choices again.

Now the program just halts there after first iteration . The client side doesnt execute "ch=raw_input("ENTER choice") " ever .

What could be possibly wrong?

server.py

```
import socket
import thread

def search(key):
    f=open("sample.txt","r")
    data =f.read()
    words = data.split()
    for word in words:
        print (word)
        if word == key:
            f.close()
            return True
    f.close()
    return False




def single_client(conn,addr):
    print ("accepted connection from",addr)
    while True:
        conn.send("1. Search a word Example : ''Python' \n 2. Count its occurrence \n 3. Position of a word\n 4. Find a word for maximum length\n 5 Count the lines \n 6. Exit \n")
        print ("sent choices")
        choice = int(conn.recv(1024))
        print (choice)
        if choice==1:
            key =conn.recv(1024)
            print (key)
            conn.send(str(search(key)))
        if choice == 6:
            print("conn terminated with ",addr)
            return 

host= socket.gethostname()
port =12345

s =socket.socket()

s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    conn,addr =s.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(single_client,(conn,addr,))


conn.close()
s.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    print(s.recv(1024))

    ch=raw_input("ENTER choice")
    print ("trying"+ch )
    s.send(ch)
    ch = int(ch)
    if ch == 1:
        s.send(raw_input("ENTER string"))
        print(s.recv(1024))

    if ch ==6:
        break



s.close()
```

Comment: Try restarting the server. I didn't have the issue you're experiencing. But what can commonly happen with this type of program is that you use your conn.recv() on the receiving end when you have sent more than one message, and you lose synchronization with the server. That is where the blocking effect comes from.